# How to make 4 quadrant Java Swing GUI whose sides always conforms to the golden ratio?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I want a rectangular GUI with 4 quadrants. The ratio of the height to the width of the JFrame (not including the minimize/maximize/close buttons) should be 1 to phi, where phi equals the golden ratio (roughly 1.62).

[image: Four quadrant GUI with sides corresponding to the golden ratio]

Now, for the four quadrants inside the JFrame. The JFrame has a horizontal dividing line that splits the height into two parts, an upper and a lower. The ratio between the height of the upper and the height of the lower should also be phi to one. Finally, the JFrame has a vertical dividing line that splits the width into two parts, a left and a right. The ratio between the left side and the right side should also be one to phi. See image above.

Now, here's the tough part. I want these four components to always obey the ratios no matter what Swing component (JScrollPane, JList, JTextArea, JPanel, JTree, or JButton) gets put into the corresponding grid location. For example, I want to be able to start with four JButtons in the four grid locations, and then swap one of the JPanels with a JScrollPane that has a JList in it without the inner component changing the relative ratios of the outer components, even if the inner component has some text or data or something in it. See image below.

[image: Adding a JTree messed up the ratios of the dividing lines]

No matter how hard I try to implement it (using GridBadLayout and a set of constrains), I can't get the gridlines to stay put. How do I make the gridlines stay in place?

So far I have source code that looks like this:

```
public static final double GOLDEN_RATIO = 1.6180339887498948482;
public static final double RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE = 1 / GOLDEN_RATIO;
public static final double RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE = 1 - (1/GOLDEN_RATIO);

// ...

    // make GridBagLayout
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    // Make 4 components to put in the four grid spaces.
    JButton filler1 = new JButton();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE;
    c.weighty = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    filler1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    filler1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    pane.add(filler1, c);

    JButton filler2 = new JButton();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE;
    c.weighty = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    filler2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    filler2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    pane.add(filler2, c);

    JButton filler3 = new JButton();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE;
    c.weighty = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    filler3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    filler3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    pane.add(filler3, c);

    JButton filler4 = new JButton();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE;
    c.weighty = RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    filler4.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    filler4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    pane.add(filler4, c);

    // Set the size of the enclosing panel.
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
            (int)(screen_height_*RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE), 
            (int)(screen_height_*RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE))
    );
```

Also, no matter how small I make the size, it should never look like this:
[image: Ratios way off]

Comment: use GridBagLayout, a few attempts for proportional resize in SSCCE/MCVE form here, including anchor, don't to use setPreferredSize nor setMinimum/PreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0)); with zero value

Comment: This question is a repost - I was going to delete the old version because it was downvoted. If you want a SSCCEE/MCVE, see the source code at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178940/java-swing-bug-causing-jtextarea-to-resize-improperly-when-line-wrapping-enabled/30180111#30180111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupLayout` to do the work for you.

**Edit:** Added the swap button

Example:

[image: test1]

[image: test1]
[image: test1]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static final double GOLDEN_RATIO = 1.6180339887498948482;
    public static final double RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE = 1 / GOLDEN_RATIO;
    public static final double RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE = 1 - (1 / GOLDEN_RATIO);
    private static final int screenHeight = 500;
    private static final int LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO = (int) (screenHeight * RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE);
    private static final int LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO = (int) (screenHeight * RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE);
    private static final int MIN_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO = (int) (50 * RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE);
    private static final int MIN_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO = (int) (50 * RELATIVE_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE);

    public Test() {
        buildGUI();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void buildGUI() {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        // make GridBagLayout
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(layout);

        // Make 4 components to put in the four grid spaces.
        JButton filler1 = new JButton("Press here to swap");
        JButton filler2 = new JButton("Press here to swap");
        JButton filler3 = new JButton("Press here to swap");
        Object[] objects = new Object[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            objects[i] = "Test" + i;
        }
        JTree jTree = new JTree(objects);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTree);
        JButton button = new JButton("Press here to swap");
        JPanel filler4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        filler4.add(button);
        ActionListener l = (e) -> {
            if (filler4.getComponents()[0] instanceof JButton) {
                filler4.remove(button);
                filler4.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            } else {
                filler4.remove(scrollPane);
                filler4.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            filler4.repaint();
            filler4.revalidate();
        };
        filler1.addActionListener(l);
        filler2.addActionListener(l);
        filler3.addActionListener(l);
        button.addActionListener(l);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(filler1, MIN_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(filler2, MIN_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                )
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(filler3, MIN_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(filler4, MIN_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                ));
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(filler1, MIN_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(filler3, MIN_LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_SHORTER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                )
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(filler2, MIN_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(filler4, MIN_LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, LENGTH_OF_LONGER_SIDE_FOR_RATIO, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                ));
        add(pane);
        setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Test().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks good. I'm going to test it rigorously and see how it does.

Comment: There's a problem when you try to make it really really small. It doesn't maintain the same ratio between grid components across all window sizes.

Comment: Especially if there is a JTextArea or a JList inside of a JScrollPane in one of the four boxes.

Comment: You can check it now, added a new pic, just needed to change the  min height and width of each group from 0 to like 29-31 or so..

Comment: Lemme check it in a minute. I added a new picture of the re-sizing problem I was having to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html). The only method I think you'd really need to implement is layoutContainer. In this method, you can setup the subcomponents (should be 4) using the ratios you've specified

Comment: I've never really subclassed LayoutManager to create my own custom swing layout before. You say it's as easy as overriding the layoutContainer(Container parent) method, but I don't really know exactly what to do. Can I get a bit more information?

Comment: I still don't know how exactly I would go about doing that.

Comment: Using group-layout messes up the grid-lines when I make the size smaller than a certain amount, but I'll have to go with the group-layout because I don't know how to do what you're advising me to do.